# Do WeldConstraints still work with MeshParts and do they still show lines when pressing alt/option?

Tags: game-development, roblox

I have started watching a tutorial by Alvin Blox about making a hatching system. At the start he connects the pet using Weld Constraints. Is that still necessary to do? If it is, does it still show lines? And if it does, does it work with MeshParts? Because a few of the parts I am using are MeshParts, including the main part.

I tried turning Anchor and CanCollide on and off and try to see if lines would appear when pressing alts (which based on the information in the video is meant to show the WeldConstraints are working properly).

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I watched more videos about it and it said I need to turn on the "Show welds" in the Constraints menu. The problem is fixed.